# Tiled background image cost bandwidth

Tags: html, css, bandwidth

If I made a background for a page as a 10 kb image which is tiled 100 times in the page, will every time a person loads the page, 1000  kb is taken from bandwidth? or only 10 kb once for the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10kb it is. that's why tiled pattern is recommended and are in fashion for website backgrounds